# Yii2 ActiveForm input-group

Tags: php, html, yii2, active-form

I want to display `input-group-btn` on `ActiveForm`, but `ActiveForm` always displays input inside div. How can I get rid of it ?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every created field you can change his encode propierties using [Options value](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#$options-detail)

```
'options' => [
    'tag' => null,
    'class' => 'foo',
    'id' => 'bar',
],
```

If you dont want any tag, you can set `tag` property as `NULL` or set it as `article`, whatever you want.

Comment: I don't know about tag, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found this http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/49225-activeform-how-do-you-call-label-input-and-errors-individually/ so I just use

```
<?php echo $form->textField($user,'email',array('size'=>32,'maxlength'=>64)); ?>
```